# Setup an ssh jump when the second connection uses gsissh

Tags: unix, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, globus-toolkit

I can run the following command to accomplish what I am trying to do, however I would like to setup entries in my ~/.ssh/config to handle a transparent jump:

`ssh -tt login.domain.org gsissh -tt -p 2222 remote.behind.wall.domain.org`

Note that the second hop MUST be made with gsissh, some info can be found here: http://toolkit.globus.org/toolkit/docs/5.0/5.0.4/security/openssh/pi/

AFAIK this precludes the standard use of `netcat` or the `-W` flag in the `ProxyCommand` option in the `.ssh/config`. I think this is because ssh will try to use ssh instead of gsissh on the intermediate machine.

If I put something like this in my `.ssh/config` it will hop through to the target machine, but when I exit I will land in a shell on the intermediate machine and it borks my ControlMaster setup—the next time I try to ssh to the final destination I end up on the intermediate machine

```
Host dest
  HostName login.domain.org
  PermitLocalCommand yes
  LocalCommand gsissh -p 2222 remote.behind.wall.domain.org
```

Also, it seems that trickery using -L or -R is disabled for security reasons.

I would love some help if anybody has any tips.
Thanks